# save images in folders by posts, not by dates

Tags: php, wordpress, image, media

I am using WordPress locally, trying to finish a small uploading program with custom posts.

The Media Files are automatically saved in Folders **by year and month**.

What can I do so I can save my images in Folders **by the title of the posts**?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please give us some more detail and code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and enjoy SO :-)

Comment: have you looked at this? https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-url-path-enabler/

Comment: i am checking the https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-url-path-enabler/ , but its been 3 years since it has been updated !

Comment: Note that all the uploads will be in front end . Uploading an Image will be only needed when a Post is Created !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function save_attachment_meta($post_id, $post, $update){
    global $wpdb;
    $currentDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    // First check if the file appears on the _FILES array


            $files = $_FILES['image_field_name'];
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

            $post_dirname =                                                                                                              $upload_dir['basedir'].'/'.$post->post_title.'_'.$post_id;
            $post_dirname = $post_dirname;
            $permissions = 0777;
            $oldmask = umask(0);
            if (!is_dir($post_dirname)) 
                mkdir($post_dirname, $permissions);
                umask($oldmask);
                chmod($post_dirname, $permissions);


            $user_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'].'/'.$post_dirname;

            //define('UPLOADS',$user_dirname);
            foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
                if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
                    $file = array( 
                        'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                        'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
                        'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
                        'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                        'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                    ); 
                $_FILES = array ("my_file_upload" => $file); 
                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {  
                //echo $user_dirname;
                    $uploaded =   move_uploaded_file($array['tmp_name'],$user_subdirMname.'/'.$array['name']);
                    $filename = $array['name'];
                    $msg = '';
                    if($uploaded != 1){
                            $msg =  "Error uploading file. ";
                    }else{
                        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null  );
                          $attachment = array(
                             'guid'           => $user_url . '/' . str_replace(' ','%20',basename( $filename )),
                             'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                             'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
                             'post_content' => '',
                             'post_status' => 'inherit'
                          );
                          $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, 37 );
                          // you must first include the image.php file
                          // for the function wp_generate_attachment_metadata() to work

                           $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
                            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );

                            if(isset($_GET['id'])):
                                ////code update attactment 
                            else:

                                ////code insert attactment 

                            endif;

                            $wpdb->query($sql);

                     $msg = "File upload successful!";


                    }
                }
                }
            }
    }
    return $msg;
}
```

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_attachment_meta', 10, 3 );

Comment: Thank you , 
I am using the code you sent to me , i can see the folder that has been created !! But the image is not in, the folder is empty

Comment: also the last --> } of the code was red, so i removed it ! Can you tell me what i am missing here? because with your help, i think i am very close

Comment: Hi, i am trying to communicate with you @yogesh ! Can you please help me with this function of your example ? if(isset($_GET['id'])):
                                ////code update attactment 
                            else:

                                ////code insert attactment 

                            endif;

Comment: if(isset($_GET['id])) /// update post query if post id exist ///// else: ///insert new post with image post data///

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ways for it.

1. Use the plugin to get the images saved by title.
2. Use images tags when you are uploading them

Comment: Which plugin can you suggest me ?

Comment: You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-image-attributes-from-filename-with-bulk-updater/